# CSS perspective with rotate & translate issue

Tags: css, rotation, transform, perspective

I am attempting to make a type of CSS only slide transition from one content section to another. In order to do so in an interesting way, I use CSS's `perspective` and `rotateX` to in essence lay down the page content. I then am trying to slide the content out towards the bottom of the screen using `translateY`

Separately, both the `translateY` and the `rotateX` work perfectly, no matter what the `perspective` is. However, when combined, it only works with certain `perspective`s based on the window size and `rotateY` value

In [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/adnFL/5/) it works as I would like it to in the window sizes I have tried. The problem is that I would like the `perspective` value to be lower, around `250px`, but I cannot do so without breaking the animation.

I tried using a higher `rotateY` degree instead of making the `perspective` lower but the same issue occurs

```
@keyframes slide {
  0% { transform: perspective(450px); }
  25% { transform: perspective(450px) rotateX(30deg); }
  50%,100% { transform: perspective(450px) rotateX(30deg) translateY(100%);  }
}
```

I have tested this on CSS Deck and jsFiddle both in FireFox and Chrome and it seems to be a consistent issue

Can anyone provide me with a reason why this is happening and offer a work around?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the `perspective` as a separate rule on a parent element (as opposed to being part of the `transform` in the `animation`).

```
.parent {
    perspective: 250px;
}

@keyframes slide {
    25% { transform: rotateX(30deg); }
    50%, 100% { transform: rotateX(30deg) translateY(100%); }
}
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/DYpnU/

My reasoning:

1. The `perspective` does not change during the animation so there's no point in having it as part of the animation.
2. Since your elements occupy 100% of the parent's area, setting the `perspective` on the parent should produce the same result as setting it on the elements themselves (inside `transform`).
3. It seems to solve your problem (see fiddle above).

**UPDATE:** after more experimentation, I found that explicitly setting the `translateY(0)` initial value in the animation would solve the issue as well.

```
@keyframes slide {
    0% { transform: perspective(150px); }
    25% { transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(30deg) translateY(0); }
    50%, 100% { transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(30deg) translateY(100%); }
}
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/YJS3v/

Comment: Wonderful work around, +1! I was able to get [the effect I want](http://jsfiddle.net/DYpnU/4/) using this approach. I'm still curious as to why the original method doesn't work though. Any thoughts?

Comment: My thought is because your `perspective` is attached to the element itself, and because your element is changing its shape and position during animation, the `perspective-origin` is also shifting and causing the animation to play different than expected, especially when the perspective value is too small, which intensifies the 3D transformations.

Comment: But why would the perspective origin jump to such a far away value, essentially reversing the way the animation displays? I don't understand how it could have that capability

Comment: Just updated the answer with another solution. I am working on the reasoning :P and will update soon.

Comment: So I don't have a definitive answer as to why the animation was playing the way it was. Things that seem to have a role in this are 1. the fact that your `translateY(100%)` could be a very big number depending on your window size, and 2. the fact that you're using a small value for perspective, which means that the perspective vanishing point is very close to the viewer, which means that CSS transformation effects are going to be intensified. You can try reducing the frame/window size to a very small size (which means small `translateY(100%)` value) and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 2):

Only a slight improvement over myajouri answer.

At leats in Chrome, you can write

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(50vh); }
  10%,15% { -webkit-transform: perspective(50vh) rotateX(30deg) translateY(0%); }
  50%,100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(50vh) rotateX(30deg) translateY(100%);  }
}
```

Setting the perspective to the viewport height should make it more responsive that your current setting

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adnFL/11/show)

(Untested in other browsers)

Comment: I'd been struggling for ages with getting perspective to work on a responsive 3D shape using "vw", changing it to "vh" was a magic solution so if anyone else has a similar issue, for some reason vh works a lot better than vw for responsive 3d!